# Cmdline Bash Variable Weirdness

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, environment-variables

I want to set an alias like so:

```
alias hi='TEST=ok echo $TEST'
```

However, it doesn't seem to work reliably.

I start with:

```
unalias hi
unset TEST
```

Then:

```
$ alias hi="TEST=ok echo $TEST"
$ hi
$
```

This is on MacOSX:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin9.0)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with aliases. Simply running

```
$ TEST=ok echo $TEST

$
```

does not echo anything (except a newline), since $TEST is expanded by the shell before the echo command is run.

Three things are happening in that statement in this order:

1. `$TEST` is expanded
2. `TEST` is assigned 'ok'
3. `echo` is executed (with TEST=ok in its environment)

Placing a semicolon between the assignment and the echo command as suggested by ghostdog74 (`TEST=ok ; echo $TEST`) causes the assignment to be a separate shell command executed before the echo command. The shell can then expand `$TEST` in the second command because it has already been set.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the semicolon

`alias hi='TEST=ok ;echo $TEST'`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

```
$ echo 'echo $TEST'>echotest
$ unset $TEST
$ TEST=ok . ./echotest
ok
$ chmod u+x echotest
$ TEST=ok ./echotest
ok
$ echo $TEST
$
```

In this case, setting `TEST=ok` modifies the environment of the script `echotest` which does not expand the `$TEST` inside it until it's run.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'd tried it from the command line and thought it had worked w/o the ';' but I suppose that was a mistake where I hadn't unset the variable first!